# Reverse page calculation algorithm

Tags: javascript

I am currently using the following algorithm to drive a page indexing system I have on my platform.

```
  getPageIndex(length, currentPage, itemsPerPage) {
    return {
      total: length,
      perPage: itemsPerPage,
      currentPage: currentPage,
      lastPage: Math.ceil(length / itemsPerPage),
      from: ((currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage) + 1,
      to: currentPage * itemsPerPage
    };
  }
```

It currently returns the following, but I would like it to return the result in reverse.

For example, on page 1, the `from` should be 699 and `to` should be 689. How would I refactor the algorithm so it behaves this way?

```
{
  "total": 699,
  "perPage": 10,
  "currentPage": 1,
  "lastPage": 70,
  "from": 1,
  "to": 10
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could substract the `length` from both to reverse the page offset and limit.

```js
function getPageIndex(length, currentPage, itemsPerPage) {
  return {
    total: length,
    perPage: itemsPerPage,
    currentPage: currentPage,
    lastPage: Math.ceil(length / itemsPerPage),
    from: Math.min(Math.max(length - ((currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage), 0), length),
    to: Math.min(Math.max(length - (currentPage * itemsPerPage), 0), length)
  };
}

var idx = getPageIndex(699, 1, 10);
console.log(idx);
```

I used `min()` and `max()` to constraint the numbers, since values greater than `length` or below `0` would make no sense.